# Are a uniformly random polynomial's roots are distributed uniformly in the field?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, probability-distributions

Assume we have a $\mathbb{F}_p$, where $p$ is a large prime (e.g. 128-bit value).

We define all polynomials over the field, and pick a polynomial,$P(x)$, of degree $d$, where the polynomials' coefficients are drawn uniformly random from the field.

---

**Question**: Are the roots of the polynomial, $P(x)$, distributed uniformly over the field?

or can we say that the polynomial's roots (if it has any) are uniformly random elements of the field?

Comment: No, because some of the polynomials might be irreducible in $\Bbb{F}_p$

Comment: @Qwerty You mean they may not have any root at all?

Comment: Yes I mean that

Comment: @Qwerty ok, I meant if it has any root, would the root be uniformly random element of the field.

Answer (score 1):

Think it in the reverse way; Say your field contains $n$ elements. Choose uniformly any number of value from the field, say $p_1,p_2,\cdots , p_k|k\le n$

It is sure that $P(x)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^k(x-p_i)\in\Bbb{F}[x]$

Comment: Thanks, it raises two questions: (1) is $P(x)$ in your answer a uniformly random  polynomial in the field? (2) is $P(x)$ in my question a uniformly random polynomial of the field. Or are they equivalent?

Comment: @user153465 As I said If you choose $P(x)$ first it can be either irreducible or may have roots. However for those that have roots, definitely they are uniformly distributed.And please upvote and accept if you liked my answer

Comment: @Qwerty Your $P(x)$ is not distributed uniformly over all polynomials with $k$ roots. For instance, consider the polynomials $x^2$ and $x(x-1)$. Both polynomials should have the same probability of occurring. But there is only one way to get $x^2$ ($p_1=0, p_2=0$), while there are two ways of getting $x(x-1)$. ($p_1=0, p_2=1$ or $p_1=1, p_2=0$).

Comment: @DPoole I meant to say that the probability that 1 is a root= the probaility that 0 is a root= probability that any elemnt of $\Bbb{F}$ is a root

Comment: @Qwerty Your random polynomial does have that property, but the random polynomial described in the comments to the OP is different than yours. In user153465's case, it is a polynomial whose coefficients are uniformly distributed conditioned on having at least one root.

Comment: @DPoole Both can't be uniform at the same time. If roots are uniformly chosen, then its sure to miss out those set of coefficients for which $P(x)$ has noo roots($P(x)$ is not uniform) and if $P(x)$ is chosen uniformly, there will be a disproportionate amount of those which have no roots(Hence roots not uniform)

Comment: $\mathbb F_p[x]$ is not necessarily algebraically closed. So, even if your $P(x)$ follow a uniform distribution, you still haven't taken into account those polynomials that cannot be factored into products of linear factors over $\mathbb F_p$.

Comment: @Qwerty The random polynomial *after conditioning* is no longer uniform over *all* polynomials of degree $d$. But it is uniform over all polynomials of degree $d$ that have at least one root. For instance, consider $d=2, p=3$. There are 9 (monic) polynomials, of which 6 have roots. The random polynomial described in the OP is uniform over these 6 polynomials (each has prob 1/6 of occurring). But your polynomial has $P(P(x) = x^2) = 1/9$ and $P(P(x) = x(x+1))=2/9$.

Comment: @user1551 Exactly. Thats why, I said to go the reverse way: Assume that your polynomial has at least 1 root, then follow

Answer (score 1):

Conditioned on the number of roots being $k$, the roots are uniformly distributed over all multi-sets of $\mathbb{F}_p$ of size $k$.

Let $P(x)$ be a uniformly chosen polynomial chosen from 
$$
\mathbb{P} := \{f(x) = x^d + a_1x^{d-1}+\ldots + a_{p-1} x + a_p: a_i \in \mathbb{F}_p, f(x)\text{ has at least one root in }\mathbb{F}_p\}.
$$
Each polynomial of $\mathbb{P}$ can be uniquely decomposed into polynomials
$$
P(x) = R(x) \times Q(x),
$$
where $R(x)$ is a monic polynomial which factors completely and $Q(x)$ is irreducible monic polynomial.

Let us condition on $Q(x) = Q_0(x)$ for some irreducible polynomial $Q_0(x)$ with degree $d', 0 \leq d' \leq d-1$. Now $R(x)$ is uniformly distributed over all polynomials of the form
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{d-d'} (x-\beta_i),
$$
where $\beta_i \in \mathbb{F}_p$. Note that the $\beta_i$'s are not (necessarily) uniformly distributed here. For instance, if $d-d' = 2$ and $p=3$, then $R(x)$ is uniform over the 6 polynomials $\{x^2, x(x-1), x(x-2), (x-1)^2, (x-1)(x-2), (x-2)^2\}$. In general, there is a bijection between possible polynomials $R(x)$ and all multi-sets of $\mathbb{F}_p$ of $d-d'$ elements. There are ${p-1+d-d' \choose p-1}$ possible multisets here. Since $R(x)$ is uniform over these possible polynomials, we have that for all admissible $R_0(x)$ with corresponding solutions $A_0$ (with multiplicity)
$$
P(\text{roots of }P(x)=A_0 | Q = Q_0)=P(R(x) = R_0(x) | Q = Q_0) = \frac{1}{{p-1 + d-d' \choose p-1}}.
$$
This implies that
\begin{align*}
P(\text{roots of }P(x)=A_0 | \text{deg}Q = d') &= \sum_{Q_0(x) \atop \text{deg}(Q_0)=d'} P(R(x) = R_0(x) | Q = Q_0) P(Q = Q_0| \text{deg}Q = d') \\&= \sum_{Q_0(x) \atop \text{deg}(Q_0)=d'} \frac{1}{{p-1 + d-d' \choose p-1}} P(Q = Q_0| \text{deg}Q = d') \\&= \frac{1}{{p-1 + d-d' \choose p-1}}.
\end{align*}
Therefore, conditioned on the number of roots, the multiset of roots is uniformly distributed over all multisets of $\mathbb{F}_p$ of the right size.

I would imagine that it would be harder to get the *distribution* of the number of roots of $P(x)$ though.